# Tutum HAProxy Docker Virtual Host forward to entry point path

Tags: docker, virtualhost, haproxy, tutum

I'm trying to use the [HAProxy tutum docker image](https://github.com/tutumcloud/haproxy) to load balance between two different web applications. Both web applications has an entry point of "/". At section [Virtual host and virtual path](https://github.com/tutumcloud/haproxy#virtual-host-and-virtual-path) I see that I can use virtual hosts to route to the different services. I've tried to set the `VIRTUAL_HOST` parameter for web app 1 to `*/webapp1*` and for web app 2 I've set it to `/*webapp2*`. But when try to navigate to web app 1 through HAProxy (using for example `http://haproxy-test.myname.svc.tutum.io/webapp1`) it forwards me to `http://<internal_ip_to_webapp1/webapp1`. I would like HAProxy to forward calls to `/webapp1` to `http://<internal_ip_to_webapp1>` (i.e. the entry point of web app 1). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing so i don't know it all yet. But one thing i can say:  VIRTUAL_HOST is only the HOST part of the URL, it doesn't include the path or "folders" after /. So you should use webapp1.something.com and web2.something.com. Take a look at: https://github.com/tutumcloud/haproxy#use-case-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the host name in the VIRTUAL_HOST parameter.

like `http://haproxy-test.myname.svc.tutum.io/webapp1/*`